# Instantiation of Templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor

Please see the following code:

```
// templateClassTemplate.cpp

#include <iostream>

class Account{
public:
  explicit Account(double amount=0.0): balance(amount){}

  void deposit(double amount){
    balance+= amount;
  }

  void withdraw(double amount){
    balance-= amount;
  }
  
  double getBalance() const{
    return balance;
  }

private:
  double balance;
};

template <typename T, int N>
class Array{

public:
  Array()= default;
  int getSize() const;

private:
  T elem[N];
};

template <typename T, int N>
int Array<T,N>::getSize() const {
  return N;
}

int main(){

  std::cout << std::endl;

  Array<double,10> doubleArray;
  std::cout << "doubleArray.getSize(): " << doubleArray.getSize() << std::endl;

  Array<Account,1000> accountArray;
  std::cout << "accountArray.getSize(): " << accountArray.getSize() << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This code is taken from a learning course on template initialisation.

I have two questions:

1. How is the object `Array<double,10> doubleArray` initialized since it is using a default constructor that takes no arguments?
2. How is the object `Array<Account,1000> accountArray` initialized?

Comment: Where did you get that code? Note that getSize() could be constexpr, for example. Also, using floating point types for money take a lot of care and by the looks of things here, no consideration has been taken in that respect. Work in "cents" and use an integral type.

Comment: _"How is the object intialised?"_. Forgive me, but the word "how" feels rather _vague_.  Are you asking what values the initialised object holds?  Are you asking what code gets executed?  Are you asking what rules of C++ determine the initialization steps?  Or something else?

Comment: @DrewDormann  - for instance, what code/mechanism is assigning the template parameters to their respective objects? I can see that Array<double,10> doubleArray is making an array of 10 doubles, but how is C++ doing this? With intstantiation of a regular object, the classes constructor would be called, potentially with list member assignment.

Comment: @Bathsheba - the code is a simple example of template intialisation taken from an online course - educative.io. The code would never be used for any purpose, except demonstration.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I now suspect this question is about _template instantiation_.  That a class template is not a class, but classes are created when the class template is instantiated.

Comment: @DrewDormann Consider Array<double,10> doubleArray - these are the template parameters T = double, N = 10. We have a private field - T elem[N]. How does <double, 10> get assigned to T elem[N]? Does the compiler simply 'match' them up for lack of a better expression?

Comment: @Elesian the compiler creates a new class from your template, where every `T` is replaced with `double`, and every `N` is replaced with `10`.  That class -- which you can't directly see -- is the class you are using.

Comment: Class template is not a class or a type. Type name of `doubleArray` here is `Array<double,10>`  That's the name of type. What you talk about in comment is not initialization but substitution, it's a separate step made by compiler as part of instantiation. They get matched by ids, which have template-wide scope (and able to mask ids from upper scopes). Formally, `<double,10>` is list of template arguments.   T and N are template parameters.,  compiler attempts to associate the former with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The template is instantiated by replacing the type `T` in the template with the *type* given as the first argument, and the integer `N` with the *value* of the second argument.
The same thing happens when instantiating the definition of `getSize`.

That is, `Array<double,10> doubleArray;` works exactly the same as

```
class DoubleArray10{

public:
  DoubleArray10()= default;
  int getSize() const;

private:
  double elem[10];
};

int DoubleArray10::getSize() const { return 10; }

DoubleArray10 doubleArray;
```

and `Array<Account,1000> accountArray;` works exactly like

```
class AccountArray1000{

public:
  AccountArray1000()= default;
  int getSize() const;

private:
  Account elem[1000];
};

int AccountArray1000::getSize() const { return 1000; }

AccountArray1000 accountArray;
```